# Spring model validation error

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc

I trying to validate a simple model by following some example code. I got following exception.

Here is Model:-

```
@Entity
public class Customer{

String password;
String confirmPassword;

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getConfirmPassword() {
    return confirmPassword;
}
public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
    this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
}

}
```

Validator class:-

```
@Component
public class PasswordValidator implements Validator{

@Override
public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
    //just validate the Customer instances
    return Customer.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {

    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "password",
        "required.password", "Field name is required.");

    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "confirmPassword",
            "required.confirmPassword", "Field name is required.");

    Customer cust = (Customer)target;

    if(!(cust.getPassword().equals(cust.getConfirmPassword()))){
        errors.rejectValue("password", "notmatch.password");
    }

}

}
```

Controller class that usages :-

```
@Controller
public class PasswordController {

@Autowired
private UserValidator userValidator;

@InitBinder
private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(userValidator);
}

@RequestMapping("/password")
public ModelAndView getPssword() {


    Customer customer = new Customer();//(Customer)command;
    return new ModelAndView("customerForm","customerForm",customer);
}


@RequestMapping(value="/password", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView restPostEditUser(@ModelAttribute @Validated Customer customer, 
                                     BindingResult result) {    
    if (result.hasErrors()){

        return new ModelAndView("customerForm");
    }

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("CustomerSuccess");
    model.addObject("customer", customer);;
    return model;
}               
}
```

I got following exception:-

HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid target for Validator [com.fnx.reg.validator.UserValidator@1aeb77d1]: com.fnx.reg.model.Customer@2ca7c795

exception

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid target for Validator [com.fnx.reg.validator.UserValidator@1aeb77d1]: com.fnx.reg.model.Customer@2ca7c795
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid target for Validator [com.fnx.reg.validator.UserValidator@1aeb77d1]: com.fnx.reg.model.Customer@2ca7c795
    org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.assertValidators(DataBinder.java:495)
    org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.setValidator(DataBinder.java:486)
    com.fnx.reg.controller.PasswordController.initBinder(PasswordController.java:33)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Your model class is `Customer`, validator is `PasswordValidator` but you bind `UserValidator` in your controller. does something ring bells??

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you're setting a `UserValidator` instead of `PasswordValidator` to your binder